# HDBC Driver for FireBird Database

Tags: haskell, firebird, hdbc

Can someone point me to an HDBC(Haskell) Driver for FireBird Database, Nothing turned up on Google. Is my best option at this point to use an HDBC-ODBC bridge to connect to a FireBird database from a Haskell Program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there's nothing out there yet. There is a summer of code 2009 [proposed project](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/summer-of-code/ticket/1563). Perhaps in the next summer of code, someone will take on the challenge of implementing it?